# jQuery DataTables column width is incorrect when using scrollX, a partial width container, and Bootstrap's table-sm class

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Running into a weird issue with DataTables. Basically, what I have is a container that is not full width and inside that div I have the table element:

```
<div style="width: 50%;">
    <table id="example3" class="display nowrap table table-bordered table-striped table-sm" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>ZIP / Post code</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm initializing the table with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        data.push([i, i, i, i, i]);
    }

    $('#example3').DataTable({
        data: data,
        scrollX: true
    });
});
```

Now, I would expect this to work, but what I end up with is this:

[image]

Notice how the header columns don't match up with the data.

This works perfectly fine if I remove the "table-sm" class or if the container/table is 100% width. I've tried other things like manually updating the columns (`table.columns.adjust()`) but nothing seems to work.

Anyone have any insight or ideas on how to fix this?

jsFiddle showing the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/vnbm8eh0/

Answer (score 0):

After looking and struggling for an hour or maybe a little more, it seems that the culprit is `table-sm`. If I remove it everything seems to work fine:

Here's an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    data.push([i, i, i, i, i]);
  }
  
  $('#example3').DataTable({
    data: data,
    scrollX: true
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.2/css/scroller.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.2/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:50%; margin: 0 auto;">
  <!-- Add "table-sm" to the class list of the table -->
  <table id="example3" class="display nowrap table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>ZIP / Post code</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

In case you **must/prefer to** work with the `table-sm` class, here is another solution to solve it although without using the jQuery DataTable `scrollX` option:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    data.push([i, i, i, i, i]);
  }
  
  $('#example3').DataTable({
    data: data
  });
});
```

```css
 #example3 {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    max-width: 40%;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.2/css/scroller.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.2/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:50%; margin: 0 auto;">
  <!-- Add "table-sm" to the class list of the table -->
  <table id="example3" class="display nowrap table table-bordered table-striped table-sm" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>ZIP / Post code</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```